# es6: dynamic import and template string

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, ecmascript-next

It seems we are not allowed to use a template string when we dynamically load a module with import() :

```
const moduleName = 'myModule'
import(`modules/${moduleName}`) // Error: Cannot find module 'modules/myModule'
```

The same with litteral string works:

```
import('modules/myModule').then(module => ...)
```

Is there a way to achieve a dynamic loading with a template string in es6?

**// UPDATE**

It seems to be more tricky though:

This works:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ ../pages/${route.componentPath}`)
// componentPath = 'MyModule'
```

This doesn't:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `${route.componentPath}`)
// componentPath = '../pages/MyModule'
```

I'm using a create-react-app configuration with react-router.

Comment: Dynamic imports are not part of ES6. [It's still a proposal only](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

Comment: This has nothing to do with template strings, which are just a syntactic convenience. The code is expected to work regardless whether you use template strings, string concatenation or constants. Please tell us more about your setup that might lead to the "cannot find module" error.

Comment: Yes and according to the doc: "import() accepts arbitrary strings (with runtime-determined template strings shown here), not just static string literals". Is that a bug?

Comment: Maybe not the template string itself but the evaluation of expressions within.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure the expression is evaluated just fine. So yes, it looks like a bug, but since you still didn't tell us about your setup/environment (JS engine? Transpiler? Loader?) I can't say in which product.

Comment: See my update. The behaviour is really weird.

Comment: This is a Webpack limitation IIRC. SystemJS supports fully dynamic module specifiers for dynamic imports.

Comment: Thanks. Is it documented somewhere?